# Flutter Local Storage: FileSystemException

Tags: android, flutter, dart, local-storage, flutter-dependencies

FileSystemException: An async operation is currently pending, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.ride/app_flutter/localstorage

`final LocalStorage storage = LocalStorage('localstorage_app');`

`storage.setItem("walkThrough", "finish");`

Data has been stored (setItem) and retrieved (getItem) using localstorage but still I am getting error warning like the above mentioned. I don't find the exact root cause of this. Please help me out in this case!.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the fact that setItem is an async operation, if you provide us a bigger chunk of code we can identify better how to fix this.

Ideally, you want an async function like this to be called.

```
Future<bool> setItem(String s) async {
    return await storage.setString("item", s);
  }
```